# How to populate database with pre-set data?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to run finished web app but it gives me error which is almost certainly due to app trying to find out which language version to use. I've done succesful migration but all tables (country, language etc. ) are empty. How do I populate them with data the app is looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a default DatabaseSeeder class included in a freshly installed Laravel app. It allows you to insert data to the database. Look for it in the `database/seeds` directory:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

If you want to add data to the `countries` table, write it like this:

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('countries)->insert([
        'code' => 'fra',
        'name' => 'France',
    ]);
    }
}
```

Then use the `db:seed` command to seed your database:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

That's it.

You can also create your own `Seeders`, for example a `ProductionDatabaseSeeder` or a `DummyDataSeeder`, auto run your seeders when you migrate a database or even use model factories to easily generate dummy data. See more in the laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/seeding).

Answer (score 3):

You can create default items as part of your migrations.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
    });

    $user = new App\User;
    $user->name = 'Bob';
    $user->save();
}
```

You can also [build seeders](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/seeding).

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with the approach of using the migration, so that the database will be filled with the data I need straight immediately after the rows themselves are created. However, instead of adding each record individually as in *ceejayoz*'s answer, I found it more efficient to use mass assignment functions:

```
class CreateManufacturersTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */

public function up()
{

    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string("slug")->unique();
        $table->string("name");
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Manufacturer::firstOrCreate(
        ["slug" => "bob", "name" => "Bob"]
    );
    
    Manufacturer::firstOrCreate(
        ["slug" => "alice", "name" => "Alice"]
    );

    Manufacturer::firstOrCreate(
        ["slug" => "hashim", "name" => "Hashim"]
    );
}
```

The `firstOrCreate()` method saves you from needing to create a new instance of the model *as well as* persisting every record that you just created.